# Sharepoint Content Type Workflow is not pushed to instances

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, content-type, sharepoint-designer

I have created a reusable Workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2010 and published this workflow globally in my site collection. Afterwards I associated the workflow with a custom content type (Infopath Form). This workflow starts whenever the item is created, change and also manually is allowd. So far so good.

Then I created a subsite and there a document library. In this document library I associated the content type to this document type. This also works fine. The problem is now, that no workflow is associated and running to the elements which are created upon the associated content type.

Shouldn't all content type automatically execute the workflow? What am I doing wrong?